# Vagrant SSH default key passphrase?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vagrant, private-key

I think I messed up something simple, normally you should be able to instantly connect to your Vagrant VM using `vagrant ssh`. However, it's currently different for me.

```
C:\Users\Sem\Documents\timeline>vagrant ssh
Enter passphrase for key 'C:/Users/Sem/Documents/timeline/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key':
vagrant@127.0.0.1's password:
vagrant@127.0.0.1's password:
vagrant@127.0.0.1's password:
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

I found one other person having the same issue: https://github.com/coreos/docs/issues/10#issuecomment-48903893

OS: Windows 8.1 Pro

Vagrant version: 1.7.2

Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
end
```

I did try multiple settings before, but if I use this Vagrantfile with `vagrant destroy` and `vagrant up` the problem remains.

If there is any information missing, please tell me.

Comment: How did you provision your default vagrant host?

Comment: @Johnsyweb the only thing I do now is `vagrant destroy` and `vagrant up`. Started using it today :) And if you're talking about my Vagrantfile, it's and empty one using `ubuntu/trusty64`.

Comment: Can you post your vagrantfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though I was searching for something else I found the solution to this problem.

I Added this to my Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]
end
```

It also made the internet connection in my vagrant VM super fast! :)

Answer (score 9):

Very new to vagrant and linux in general so this is for those who are like me. By default there is no passphrase so simply hitting enter will work. It will then ask you for the password which by default is 'vagrant'.

Answer (score 2):

Check permissions on your key file. I had the same problem and it was caused by OpenSSH rejecting my key file due to too open permissions. Also you can troubleshoot any Vagrant command with `--debug` key.