# How to ssh to Vagrant machine?

Tags: vagrant

I'm trying to ssh to simple Vargant machine and it asks me for passphrase:

```
>vagrant init ubuntu/trusty32
>vagrant up
>vagrant ssh
Enter passphrase for key '.../.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key':
```

This is probably due to [new key generation](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/4707):

```
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default:
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default:
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if its present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
```

How to make new keys passwordless?

**Upadate:** Looks like the key is not actually protected by passphrase. I used Puttygen to generate .ppk from it and successfully connected using it to vagrant@localhost:2200.

Comment: config.ssh.insert_key = false is referenced from that PR. I haven't had a chance to verify it for myself but a google search suggests this is the workaround people are using.

Comment: @AdamTaylor nope, insecure_private_key also asks for passphrase.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vagrant SSH default key passphrase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452656/vagrant-ssh-default-key-passphrase)

Comment: Turned out my question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452656/vagrant-ssh-default-key-passphrase/29758547. I found a solution and posted it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by OpenSSH rejecting my key file due to too open permissions. Also to troubleshoot any Vagrant command use --debug key.